# Windows Azure Startup task not firing

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, task, startup

I have a standard ASP.Net application to which I added an Azure Deployment project to deploy to Azure. The app deploys fine to Azure.

I then wanted to extend it to have a startup task.

I added the following to the ServiceDefintion.csdef

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple"/>
</Startup>
```

startup.cmd is located in the applications bin folder. I have logging the command file so I can see it is not being executed.

When I deploy the same application to the Compute Emulator on my local machine the startup task executes correctly.

Am I missing something?

Comment: AppRoot\Bin could potentially be different than the Application\bin folder. Is your application in a virtual directory?

Comment: Is the file being deployed onto the Azure box? What happens if you RDP on and manually run it?

Comment: The file is definitely been deployed to Azure, I can run it fine when I RDP to Azure.

Comment: What's in the startup.cmd?  Is it possible that startup command is being run, but whatever resource it is trying to launch is using relative pathing and not finding the exe or whatever?  I have seen that most often is the case.

Comment: Try running the .cmd file manually with a "pause" line added in. This will reveal any errors if the problem lies within your .cmd file. In my case, a strange symbol was being added in at the first line of the file and was causing the script to fail. I solved this by starting the scripting on the second line of the .cmd file instead of the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Your "startup.cmd" shall not just be in your app BIN folder, but instead in the root folder and marked as "Content" and "Copy to output directory" -> "Copy always". Otherwise it will not get deployed to the Azure.

Another moment to pay attention with Web Applications is that you most probably shall put the bin folder also in the startup task definition. Something like:

```
<Startup> 
  <Task commandLine="./bin/startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple"/> 
</Startup>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's definitely deployed. It's in the root and marked as Content and Copy Always.

Comment: using "./bin/startup.cmd" gives a path not found error on publish. If I change the name of the file in the commandLine to something invalid like startup1.cmd then the Azure publish also throws an exception which suggests to me that the file is in the right location and is been found.

Comment: I'm surprised this was not upvoted yet. This was the solution for me. However, it seemed the script was still not running. When I ran it manually though (using Remote Desktop), there was a weird symbol being inserted at the first line of my script. I don't know why it was doing this, but I ended up just starting my script on the second line of the .cmd file instead of the first line. After doing that, everything functioned correctly including the Startup Task to run the custom script.

Comment: your issue with the symbol was because of character encoding of the .cmd file. Make sure you save it as ASCII and not UTF, and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party.

I had this issue as well and for me it was that I had set the Web Role project to the startup project instead of the Azure Cloud Service project. By setting the Azure Cloud Service as the startup project you start the project with the azure emulator, which is needed to get start, run and stop events to work as in your azure environment.